# SearchBar doesn't work when I press a keyboard button

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to implement a searchbar in my project.

I have already created the SearchBar outlet, have set the delegate, but when I press any keyboard button, the value from this button does not appear in `UISearchBar`

Can anybody tell me why?

```
  - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar {

     // When the search button is tapped, add the search term to recents and conduct the search.
     NSString *searchString = [aSearchBar text];
     NSLog(searchString);
 }
```

Comment: did you implemente de UISearchBarDelegate protocol?

Comment: yes@interface Tela1ViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate> {

Comment: The problem is that when I digit , the value does not appear in bar...is as I have nothing did...

Comment: Did you set your Tela1ViewController as UISearchBar's delegate, or did you wired as delegate in Interface Builder?

Comment: yes...I did set the Tela1ViewController as Uisearchbar delegate and the Outlet I did self set

Comment: Implement also searchBar:textDidChange: , put a breakpoint on it and tell us if the code steps inside when you add text.

Comment: No, but steps inside in searchBarTextDidBeginEditing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have missed the code below in appDelegate , ***applicationDidFinishLauching***

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Now the SearchBar is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    return YES;
}
```

By returning YES you "say" that you accept editing.

**EDIT**

You don't even need to implement this method, by default a UISearchBar accepts editing.
No extra method is need to be implemented.

To be sure I've just did the following:

- Dragged a search bar in the xib file;
- Bound via xib the delegate to my view controller;
- Implemented searchBarSearchButtonClicked: and put a breakpoint on it.

Works perfectly.Make sure that you have done all in the right way.

Comment: Yes, I forgot. But now, I have implemented this method and didn't steped in this method

Comment: -(BOOL) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    return YES;
}

Comment: step in searchBarShouldBeginEditing when I click into searchBar, but when I digit...

Answer (score 0):

I have forgot this method

```
-(BOOL) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: whats is the problem them? :(

Comment: Ramy the problem persists...why? the Delegate works because step in searchBarShouldBeginEditing
 and in 
searchBarShouldEndEditing

Comment: This may be long to write in comments, let's continue here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22055/searchbar-doesnt-work-when-i-press-a-keyboard-button

Comment: Only users nominated by the room owner may talk here. See the faq for more information. You have requested talk privileges in this room; please be patient while the room owner processes your reques

Comment: Now you can write to the room if you still need some help.